# Convert a string (in date format) to datetime using Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, birt

In BIRT, i have a column containing a datetime stored as a string. I need to convert these string to datetime format and put the result in another column using Javascript. 
The string is the form of: for example: Fri 21 Feb 2014, 09:40 AM.

Hence this when converted to a datetime format and exported to excel, the column should be treat as a date.
Can any one of you help me to do it?

Cheers,

Comment: What is the converted format? Reformatting the string isn't hard, but you need to suggest what to reformat it too.

Comment: Basically i want that Fri 21 Feb 2014, 09:40 AM to behave as a datetime and not as a string. so the format of the datetime should also be the same.

Comment: That's not particularly helpful. To "behave as a datetime" infers converting to a javascript object, but is seems you want a string that Excel will treat as a date and time. Excel will handle a very wide variety of strings, but in different and probably confusing or incorrect ways. Probably the best format is some version of ISO 8601, so yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm will be the most unambiguos and produce the desired result (pasting into Excel will produce a date and time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers do not take into consideration this question is in a BIRT context.

- Create a computed column in your dataset, with "Date time" as datatype
- Enter as expression:

> new Date(row["myDateStringField"]);

Where "myDateStringField" is your DateTime column in a String format. Then use this computed column in your report instead of the String column.

That's it!

Comment: Im glad it helped! may be you could set this as valid answer, it would be helpful for other birt developers who want to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)!

You can parse your time of any format like

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

In your case, you don't even have to specify the format. It automatically recognizes it.

And you can output ISO format or convert it to a Javascript Date object.

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely easy to do with javascript.  The following code will make a date in a format that Excel will recognize as a date.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/d7SwQ/

```
var dateString = 'Fri 21 Feb 2014, 09:40 AM';
var date = new Date(dateString);
var yr = date.getFullYear();
var mo = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();

var hours = date.getHours();
var hr = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;

var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var min = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var sec = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

var newDateString = yr + '-' + mo  + '-' + day;
var newTimeString = hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

var excelDateString = newDateString + ' ' + newTimeString;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reformat 'Fri 21 Feb 2014, 09:04 AM' as '2014-02-21 09:04', then the following will do:

```
function stringToTimestamp(s) {
  var t = s.match(/[\d\w]+/g);
  var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04',may:'05',jun:'06',
                jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
  function pad(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + +n;}
  var hrs = t[4] % 12;
  hrs += /pm$/i.test(t[6])? 12 : 0;

  return t[3] + '-' + months[t[2].toLowerCase()] + '-' + pad(t[1]) + ' ' +
         pad(hrs) + ':' + pad(t[5]);
}

console.log(stringToTimestamp('Fri 21 Feb 2014, 09:04 AM')); // 2014-02-21 09:04
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for your time on this. Dom's reply was what i was expecting. But your help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

use the ISO format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS or YYYY-MM-DD

```
new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00');
```

or

```
new Date('2011-04-11');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do I use it during run time. That is, if i don't know the exact value of the datetime, and the script should take the value from the column.

Comment: make conditions in your string. if the format is ** YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS** so use the firs else if **YYYY-MM-DD** so use the second

Comment: @Alaeddine—the OP is trying to get the string into that (or similar) format. Posting an answer that converts a string that the OP doesn't have into an object that the OP doesn't want is not helpful.